# How to set a default cell value if no data present in react bootstrap table 2

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have tables rendered across multiple places with multiple data sources, implemented with [react-bootstrap-table2.](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2)

For this, I have created one single component `<MyTable ... />` which ultimately renders `<BootstrapTable .../>` component.

Is there any way to apply a rule globally that if the whatever data being passed in has a blank value, a dash '-' should be rendered by default in that case?

Having `formatter` applied on columns of each and every table is not a good idea.

Comment: "you must try to develop your own library."

Can you be more creative with your comment and tell me how exactly I must do it? I'll make it as an accepted answer if it is really helpful.

Comment: Before passing data to react-bootstrap-table2, check whether data is empty or null, if it is then add (-) dash and stored it in one array and then pass whole data to table

Answer (score 2):

You can write a common `nullChecker` and use that for the column definitions where you might expect to have NO data.

> 1. You can still keep the common Bootstrap table
> 2. You will need to update the column definitions to add a `formatter`
> 3. The `formatter` takes a reference to your `nullChecker` and returns a value or a dash (-) based on if the value is present.

Have a look at this sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-boot-table-defaultvalues-bpwgz

1. Table1 is a normal table with no missing data
2. Table2 has some missing data for 'From' and 'To' columns. The dash is shown if no value is present. For this, `nullChecker` from `helper.js` is used.